# Where are cameras mounted?

Tags: mount, automount, canon, camera

I have a **canon PowerShot A3100 IS** camera, and, as written in the title, I want to know where does the automount mount it when I connect it.

Does anyone know?

Comment: You can use the card reader and find the files at its mountpoint(If automounted, somewhere in `/media`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your camera connects over PTP, GPhoto will be responsible for the data transfers. I guess the ~/.gvfs directory will contain a virtual folder pointing to your camera.

Comment: But you can't access that folder from terminal.  Accessing it from file manager is the same as you see in my image above.

Comment: In Ubuntu, PTP cameras are handled by gvfs, which calls libgphoto in the background. So, you can find a virtual folder representing your MTP camera in ~/.gvfs, it really is that simple.

Comment: I know what you're saying.  Try accessing the folder from terminal an see :)

Answer (score 14):

With Ubuntu 12.10 I didn't have any luck with `~/.gvfs`... However, I'm able to access my camera on the command line using

```
/run/user/<username>/gvfs/gphoto2:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C008%5D/
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04, instead of my username it was my [User Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) (UID) (which for me was `1000`). And I have to open the camera from `nautilus` (Ubuntu's file manager) before I see it in `/run/user/1000/gvfs`

Answer (score 4):

## Mount it using `gphotofs`

Install `gphotofs` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gphotofs
```

Then create a directory wherever you prefer (i'm using  `/home/<user>/camera`)

```
mkdir /home/<user>/camera
```

And use the following to mount it

```
sudo gphotofs /home/<user>/camera
```

#### notes

- replace `<user>` with your username

Comment: This worked like a charm - but *without* "sudo" in the gphotofs command; at first I did this with sudo and couldn't access the camera, even with sudo chown <user>:<user> /home/<user>/camera

Answer (score 2):

You can open the gphoto2:// address directly in your file manager.  Nautilus handles it and gives you a device.  Other browsers such as thunar you may have to enter the address manually.

~/.gvfs is the default mountpoint produced by the gvfs-fuse-daemon (package gvfs-fuse).  This is a but temperamental so even if you have the package installed it may fail at startup.  Check the permissions on .gvfs.

Depending on your environment (varies between versions), you may have an XDG_RUNTIME_DIR set and then .gvfs will be mounted there instead of your home dir.  Typically this will be something like /run/user/...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it gets mounted at `gphoto2://[usb:001.006]/`

[image]

Not all cameras are mountable. The gphoto2 command should allow you to download pictures from supported cameras.

If your camera is like that, you can avoid this problem by using a USB card reader. The USB card reader makes any card mountable, just like a hard drive.

Comment: Yeah but what does **gphoto2://[usb:001.006]/** mean ? .. where is it ?

Comment: Its listed in your file manager.  See the image in the background. :)

Comment: Yes but what if I wanted to access to it from the command line ? :/

Answer (score 1):

While this is true [about gphoto2 mounting cameras], there is a setting on some cameras that allow you to connect them actually as a USB mass storage device (see screenshot), then you do not have to rely on gphoto2 and can treat your camera (or the card within it) as a normal usb flash disk. The setting to change how your camera connects to the PC is not present in all camera menus, but is usually in DSLRs. It often makes transferring your pictures and videos easier to have this setting on USB mass storage- at least it works for me[image: Nikon D70 mass storage]

Comment: I don't find that option in the camera. However I'll search for that. thanks

Comment: If there isn't an option in your camera menu, you can take out the memory card and put it in a usb card reader and connect it to the computer. Then you should be able to read and write from the card with no problems.

Comment: Yep, I thought about that. But like I said to Mr Mitch, what if I wanted to access to my camera from the command line ?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 19.04, Nautilus (Ubuntu's file manager) mounts cameras at

```
/run/home/$UID/gvfs/gphoto2:host=Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers
```

Where `$UID` is your [User Identifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) (it's probably `1000`).

The last folder in the file path is probably different for your camera. You can find the string by doing

```
gio mount --list --detail
```

And looking for a line like

```
activation_root=gphoto2://Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers
```

For me, the camera would not get mounted unless I opened Nautilus and clicked on the camera. To mount it manually from the command line I did

```
gio mount gphoto2://Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers
```

And to unmount it I did

```
gio mount -u gphoto2://Name_of_Company_Model_Name_SomeNumbers
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's mounted somewhere, you can go to the terminal and execute mount without parameters to see a list of mounted devices and their locations.

Regards